# How to pass a map to a Jenkins Pipeline global function?

Tags: dictionary, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a [global function](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin#define-more-structured-dsl) like this:

```
def myStep(Closure body) {
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config

    body()

    echo config.name      // works
    echo config.configure // is null
}
```

Which is called like this:

```
myStep {
    name = 'linux-build'
    configure = [os: 'linux', dir: 'build']

    echo "myStep"
}
```

Normal variables (`name`) are working but the passed map (`configure`) does not. Maybe that is because of `def config = [:]`? How can I access the map inside the function?

Answer (score 4):

The `Map` is really passed the problem is that `echo` don't know how to deal with `Map` in order to print in the console (seems that `echo` only prints string).

So you can try with the follow code instead:

```
echo config.configure.toString() // prints [os:linux, dir:build]
```

Or using `GString`:

```
echo "${config.configure}" // prints [os:linux, dir:build]
```

Or using `println`:

```
println config.configure // prints  {os=linux, dir=build}
```

So the thing is that `Map` is there so you can access `config.configure.os` or `config.configure.dir` without problems, try with the follow code in the jenkins-pipeline:

```
def myStep(Closure body) {
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config

    body()

    echo config.name      // works
    echo config.configure.os // prints linux
    echo config.configure.dir // prints buid
    println config.configure // prints {os=linux, dir=build}
}

myStep {
    name = 'linux-build'
    configure = [os: 'linux', dir: 'build']
    echo "myStep"
}
```

It shows the follow result in the *Output console*:

```
[Pipeline] echo
myStep
[Pipeline] echo
linux-build
[Pipeline] echo
linux
[Pipeline] echo
build
[Pipeline] echo
{os=linux, dir=build}
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```